# VBA Code to go for specific slide in MS Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I Have a powerpoint with 6 slides. I have set the advanced auto timer of 2 minutes. I want to set a rule where if the person clicks on the slide before the auto timer time, i want the presentation to start from 1st slide again.
Is there a way to achive this.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this, the slides don't appear to have an OnClick event you can tap into... unless i'm missing something.

Comment: Just an incomplete thought here, but PPT fires a SlideShowNextSlide event whenever the slide changes ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.Application.SlideShowNextSlide ) Possibly fire off a timer when that event triggers and if the timer's < Autotimer amount when the event fires again, go to the first slide.